MySQL ST_GeomFromText Setting Point is mixing up Lat and lng for point in Austrailia
I have a table with Lat and Lng fields as doubles. I have added POINT field, and am trying to run an update over the table to create the points. This works for most records, but I have a point in Austrailia which does not work.
UPDATE points
SET point_4326 = ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', Lng, ' ', Lat, ')'), 4326)
WHERE point_id = 4601

The values are : Lat = -33.484806894966
Lng = 151.33459992068
The error received is : #3617 - Latitude 151.334600 is out of range in function st_geomfromtext. It must be within [-90.000000, 90.000000].
I have tried putting the values in directly like this.
UPDATE points
SET point_4326 = ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', '151.33459992068', ' ', '-33.484806894966', ')'), 4326)
WHERE point_id = 4601

It looks like it is treating the Lat value as Lng.
I am using mySQL v8.0.35

Make sure that point_4326 is a POINT type with SRID 4326 defined in the table, as different SRID values might interpret the coordinates differently. Your code is for SRID 4326 so if you have anything else selected for point_4326 select SRID 4326. Since you named your POINT 'point_4326' you probably did select it but check it twice.
If everything is as I told you then try running your query but switch Lng and Lat. If it doesn't show error do SELECT query to see row id 4601 and check if Lng and Lat values are correctly inputed. If yes-reply to this, we'll figure it out then.

Thanks. The column was setup like this
ALTER TABLE points ADD point_4326 POINT NULL AFTER point_id;
ALTER TABLE points MODIFY point_4326 POINT SRID 4326 NULL;
If I swap the paramers around, I do not get the error, but the lat and lng are the incorrect ways round if I do this query. SELECT point_id, ST_X(point_4326) AS lng, ST_Y(point_4326) AS lat FROM points WHERE point_id = 4601
